# Mybatis insert fail when add more parameter

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

I'm using `Mybatis` `3.2`, `Orace 12c` for my project. I used code generator to generate `insert()` method. In the `<insert>` tag it has schema name; for ex:

```
insert into CPORTAL.CARD_USER_MASTER
```

Now, the schema is dynamic, so I put the parameter to change the schema:

```
insert into ${schema}.CARD_USER_MASTER
```

Parameter `schema` is defined in `mapper.java` as

```
insert(CardUserMaster record, @Param("schema") String schema)
```

However, without that schema, insert works but when has schema, error happen:

```
 org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'carduserSeqno' not found. Available parameters are [0, schema, param1, param2]
```

In other class I set schema parameter like that on `insert` method and it works. Don't know what happen to this class.

Any comments will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
insert(@Param("entity") CardUserMaster record, @Param("schema") String schema)
```

and use the params as `entity.carduserSeqno` in the SQL.

Looks like it cannot recognize that 0 parameter is POJO. Without the `@Param("schema")` it uses pojo fields directly as params btu with adding the `schema` param it cannot.

Comment: thanks, but not work as I expected. Anyway, appreciate your help. Cheers.